# Minecraft Bukkit plugin custom sounds without resource packs

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit, ogg

I have never had any experience with java but have managed to get something happening. What I want is to take my custom Minecraft map (Sonic Dash) and instead of making people get a resource pack I want to add the custom .ogg files I have made and make the plugin play them.

I already have the plugin created I just don't know how to add custom sound effects and get eclipse to play them without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. This is as custom sound files must be played on the client and a plugin is incapable of sending these. You must use a resource pack if you want to play any sounds apart from the existing ones. Sorry for the disappointing answer, but it is important to understand the capabilities and limits of a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can play .nbs files as noteblock sounds.
Try https://github.com/xxmicloxx/NoteBlockAPI
Convert from midi to .nbs http://www.stuffbydavid.com/mcnbs